# Finding a limit of the function $y(x)e^{y(x)}=e^{x+1}$

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

The question defines the function : $y(x)e^{y(x)}=e^{x+1}$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

The question wants you to find: $$\lim_{x\to-\infty } y(x)$$

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Note that $y(x)=e^{-y(x)}e^{x+1}>0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$ which implies that that any limit value is non-negative. Let $(x_n)_n$ be a sequence such that $x_n\to -\infty$, and $\lim_{n\to+\infty } y(x_n)=L\in [0,+\infty)$
then
$$Le^L=\lim_{n\to+\infty }y(x_n)e^{y(x_n)}=\lim_{n\to +\infty }e^{x_n+1}=0.$$
Can the limit be $+\infty$? What may we conclude about the existence and the value of the limit $\lim_{x\to-\infty } y(x)$?

Comment: I'd say we need to show that the limit exists, too.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy This is a hint and of course one should prove that the limit exists.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From $y(x)=e^{x+1-y(x)}>0$ and then $y(x)=e^{x+1-y(x)}<e^{x+1}$, we find $\lim_{x\to-\infty}y(x)$ by squeezing.